# Apps crash after 20-30 minutes Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, crash, fsck

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04 since mid-August, and this particular problem started today. For some reason, the computer wouldn't start this morning, and had an fsck error. I ran `fsck -a /dev/`(I don't remember what, but whatever file was giving the error), which allowed me to restart, but now I'm having issues with apps crashing.

I first noticed it in Chrome and Firefox--after about half an hour, tabs would start to crash, then quickly the entire program would crash. However, I noticed the same issue in VSCode, then eventually Signal began refusing to start. I uninstalled Firefox, Chrome, and VSCode, and re-downloaded all of them as `.deb` files, but that didn't fix the problem. I checked the `systemood` log, but it hasn't killed anything. Only next step I could find would be reinstalling Ubuntu or replacing the hard drive, but I'd rather not do either if I can avoid it.

FWIW, about a month ago the system often won't wake up from sleep. It's on, but I have to turn it off and on again to use it. I was able to substantially curtail this issue by adding a line to one of the system files--I don't think it was a grub file, but I can't find the one it was.

Edit: Error, as asked.

```
(base) schmiggle@Anodosa:~$ Gtk-Message: 09:42:53.983: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 09:42:53.985: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
amdgpu: os_same_file_description couldn't determine if two DRM fds reference the same file description.
If they do, bad things may happen!
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 14690
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
```

Crashing here was caused by trying to use google drive.

Comment: Run `firefox` from the command line, keep using it until it crashes, and post the error message from terminal when it crashed.